# Looping through multidimensional array to get specific results from sub arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array and I would like to extract some data out of the array. That is normally no problem for me but this time it is a little bit different for me.

I have this array:

```
$arrParcelLabelNumber = array
(
    "parcelLabelNumber" => array
    (
        0 => "10",
        1 => "20"
    ),
    "weight" => array
    (
        0 => "1111",
        1 => "2222"
    )
);
```

I would like to have the following result:
10 = 1111,
20 = 2222

So that means I want the value of parcelLabelNumber where the key is the same as the one from weight and I want then also the value of the weight where they are both the same.

I tried several methods but all of them didn't work.

New code:

```
$arrParcelLabelNumber = array
(
    "parcelLabelNumber" => array
    (
        0 => "09988014801055",
        1 => "09988014801056"
    ),
    "weight" => array
    (
        0 => "1111",
        1 => "2222"
    )
);

foreach($arrParcelLabelNumber as $val){
     foreach($val['parcelLabelNumber'] as $key=>$v){
        echo $val['weight'][$key] . "=" . $v;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with a simple for too:

```
$c = count($arrParcelLabelNumber["parcelLabelNumber"]);

for ($i = 0; $i< $c; $i++)
{
    if(isset($arrParcelLabelNumber["parcelLabelNumber"][$i]) && isset($arrParcelLabelNumber["weight"][$i])){
        echo $arrParcelLabelNumber["parcelLabelNumber"][$i] . " = " . $arrParcelLabelNumber["weight"][$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this one worked after i changed $c++ to $i++ in the for else you get a infinite loop :P

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($arrParcelLabelNumber as $val){
     foreach($val['parcelLabelNumber'] as $key=>$v){
         echo $val['weight'][$key] . "=" . $v;
      }

}
```

Or if you wanna store them as a keyvalue pair for retrieval...

```
 $newarray=array();
 foreach($arrParcelLabelNumber as $val){
     foreach($val['parcelLabelNumber'] as $key=>$v){
        $newarray[$val['weight'][$key]] = $v;
     }
 }
 var_dump($newarray);
```

Or as a pair in an array...

```
 $newarray=array();
 foreach($arrParcelLabelNumber as $val){
    foreach($val['parcelLabelNumber'] as $key=>$v){
       $newarray[]=array('parcelLabelNumber'=>$v,'weight'=> $val['weight'][$key]);

    }
 }
```

Comment: i get an error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() it is on the second foreach

Comment: Of course you do, try to read through the function before you use it... you'll see that `$k` was used when `$key` should have been used.

Comment: @David Barker It also doesn't work when i make it $key

Comment: @KyleK I still get the same error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @user3734231 which would indicate that your data doesn't map exactly to the structure you've defined. maybe check if the key exists first.

Comment: @DavidBarker yes it does, i edited my post with the current code. And as you can see it does match.